# In Donnie Brasco, Lefty said: "You're still driving a fucking Lincoln when you get there." What's that mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, donnie-brasco

In *Donnie Brasco* the following dialogue occurs:

> Nicky: "It's a longer car. Two fucking cars, right? This is a car, this is a car, right?"
>   Lefty continues to watch Brasco. His friend talks from the Off: "Right here, okay? All things being equal, the one's longer gonna get there first. You don't have to be fucking Einstein to understand this."
>   Lefty: "You know what happens when you get there, don't you?"
>   Nicky: "No."
>   Lefty: "You're still driving a fucking Lincoln."
>   Lefty said : You're still driving a fucking Lincoln when you get there."

What's that mean? Does it means the Lincoln is slow?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but on the face of it, I'd suspect whoever said that felt that a [Limo](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=limousine&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=eqp&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&biw=1018&bih=970&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CxN0VLb1MaLymQWj4IDwBQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) beats a [Lincoln](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=lincoln+car&hs=npp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&bih=970) any way you look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've obviously watched the **Director's Cut**, going by the questions you've asked. There are some differences in the script, including this section. To quote the relevant section from the *[original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Donnie-Brasco.html)*:

> **Lefty**: Ain't no comparison. Cadillac
>                       got more acceleration, more
>                       power, more-- better handling,
>                       better looking, more legroom for
>                       your legs , more power
>
> ... other dialogue, then later:
>
> **NICKY**
>                     You got two cars. One's longer.
>                     All things being equal, the
>                     longer car is the one gonna get
>                     there first.
>                                **LEFTY**
>                     Ain't the question all things
>                     being equal. One's a Cadillac
>                     and one's a Lincoln.

In other words, **Lefty** is arguing the *Cadillac* is better. **Nicky** is arguing the *Lincoln* is better. Nicky has tried to use the argument that the longer car will get there first. Lefty, in the quotes you've provided, answers derisively that *"You're still driving a fucking Lincoln."*. Or to put it another way, it doesn't matter if you get there first, you're still driving the *inferior car*.

So in summary: his comment indicates his opinion that the Cadillac is better than the Lincoln.